# Using a SELECT statement with NOT LIKE. I would like to exclude multiple values from a column, but SQLite doesn't support REGEX

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, select

I am querying data in SQLite and I need to exclude rows according to values in one of the fields (`SaleCondition`) `CIHMNQRTUVW7`. These are the values I want to exclude but SQLite doesn't support `REGEX` and I have tried multiple `NOT LIKE %C%` statements, but they don't work.

I am using R to do this:

```r
filter_calcs1 <- dbGetQuery(nqdb, statement = "SELECT * FROM trds WHERE SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%CIHMNQRTUVW7%' ORDER BY Symbol")
```

The `SaleCondition` field can have multiple values so I need to remove values either one at at time or all at once. These are the values that have to be excluded: `CIHMNQRTUVW7`

Comment: `SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%CIHMNQRTUVW7%'` will exclude rows containing `'CIHMNQRTUVW7'` in the column `SaleCondition`. Do you want something else?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow, have you tried something like that: `...WHERE SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%C%' OR NOT LIKE '%I%' OR NOT LIKE '%H%' OR NOT LIKE '%M%'...` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using this statement: filter_calcs_x2 <- dbGetQuery(nqdb, statement = "SELECT * FROM trds WHERE SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%C%' OR NOT LIKE '%I%' OR NOT LIKE '%H%' OR NOT LIKE '%M%' OR NOT LIKE '%N%' OR NOT LIKE '%Q%' OR NOT LIKE '%R%' OR NOT LIKE '%T%' OR NOT LIKE '%U%' OR NOT LIKE '%V%' OR NOT LIKE '%W%' OR NOT LIKE '%7%' ORDER BY Symbol ")

Comment: This is the error I receive: Error: tinyformat: Too many conversion specifiers in format string

Comment: In the SaleCondition column there an be a combination of several identifiers. What I am trying to do is remove the row if there is an occurrence of any of these values. Since SQLite doesn't support REGEX it is much more difficult to remove them.

Comment: "SQLite doesn't support REGEX" : Can you not define an application-function in R that executes regex and refer to it in your SQL? Maybe worth a search on SO or the web to find an approach on how to do this and get access to the regex power you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that the problem is to remove rows for which C or I or H or ... or 7 appears in `SaleCondition`. `strFilter(SaleCondition, 'CIHMNQRTUVW7')` will return `SaleCondition` but without any character not in the second argument.  That is, the only characters in the result will be characters that are in both arguments. Thus, we only want to retain rows for which the output of `strFilter` is a zero length string.

```
SELECT *
FROM trds 
WHERE strFilter(SaleCondition, 'CIHMNQRTUVW7') = ''
ORDER BY Symbol
```

Comment: That was exactly it.  Now I can go through and find the correct min, max and avg for each stock price.  Many thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple NOT LIKE clauses you need to **AND** the conditions not **OR** them, like :-

```
SELECT * FROM trds WHERE 
    SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%CIHMNQRTUVW7%' 
        AND SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%7WVUTRQNMHIC%' 
        AND SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%ABCDEFGHIJK1%' ;
```

e.g. if the table contained rows such as :-

```
blah CIHMNQRTUVW7 to be excluded
blah CIHMNQRTUVW8 not to be excluded
blah 7WVUTRQNMHIC to be excluded
blah 8WVUTRQNMHIC not to be excluded
blah ABCDEFGHIJK0
blah ABCDEFGHIJK1
blah ABCDEFGHIJK2
```

Then the above select results in :-

```
blah CIHMNQRTUVW8 not to be excluded
blah 8WVUTRQNMHIC not to be excluded
blah ABCDEFGHIJK0
blah ABCDEFGHIJK2
```

Re Comment :-

In the SaleCondition column there an be a combination of several identifiers. What I am trying to do is remove the row if there is an occurrence of any of these values.

Say the table contains :-

```
blah CIHMNQRTUVW7 to be excluded
blah CIHMNQRTUVW8 not to be excluded
blah 7WVUTRQNMHIC to be excluded
blah 8WVUTRQNMHIC not to be excluded
blah ABCDEFGHIJK0
blah ABCDEFGHIJK1
blah ABCDEFGHIJK2
blah ABCDEFGHIJK0 ABCDEFGHIJK2
blah ABCDEFGHIJK0 ABCDEFGHIJK2 ABCDEFGHIJK1 CIHMNQRTUVW7 CIHMNQRTUVW8 7WVUTRQNMHIC will be excluded
```

The result of using the query is :-

```
blah CIHMNQRTUVW8 not to be excluded
blah 8WVUTRQNMHIC not to be excluded
blah ABCDEFGHIJK0
blah ABCDEFGHIJK2
blah ABCDEFGHIJK0 ABCDEFGHIJK2
```

So the last row that has multiple identifiers and multiple identifiers to be excluded is excluded.

An alternative and perhaps easier to understand logically is to use the **instr** function (which could be more flexible), this returns the position 1 for the first character and so on e.g. consider :-

```
SELECT * FROM trds WHERE 
    instr(SaleCondition,'CIHMNQRTUVW7') 
    + instr(SaleCondition,'7WVUTRQNMHIC') 
    + instr(SaleCondition,'ABCDEFGHIJK1') 
    = 0;
```

This query might be more helpful in understanding, it shows the logic true or false of the individual checks and then the final result :-

```
SELECT 
        SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%CIHMNQRTUVW7%' AS chk1,
        SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%7WVUTRQNMHIC%' AS chk2,
        SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%ABCDEFGHIJK1%' AS chk3,
        SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%CIHMNQRTUVW7%' 
        AND SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%7WVUTRQNMHIC%' 
        AND SaleCondition NOT LIKE '%ABCDEFGHIJK1%' AS result FROM trds

chk1    chk2    chk3    result 
0       1       1       0
1       1       1       1
1       0       1       0
1       1       1       1
1       1       1       1
1       1       0       0
1       1       1       1
1       1       1       1
0       0       0       0
```

So only if **all** of the first three columns are true (1) will the combination of the results be 1 because of the ANDS

Comment: So if one row of the data contained a SaleCondition with a combination of these values @CHTI, it would have to be excluded for the min, max and avg values to be accurate.  I guess what I am asking for is to check each value in the SaleColumn with the list of excluded modifier values.

Comment: @BruceCampbell and alternative way to look at the unnatural NOT LIKE AND NOT LIKE ... is to instead consider an alternative of the above e.g. `SELECT * FROM trds WHERE instr(SaleCondition,'CIHMNQRTUVW7') + instr(SaleCondition,'7WVUTRQNMHIC') + instr('ABCDEFGHIJK1') = 0;`. This is effectively the same but it accumulates hits (i.e. if instr is met it returns 1 or greater).

Comment: I will definitely give that a try now. I very much appreciate your helpfulness.

Comment: I ran this, but it left all of the T values so I'm not quite sure what to do at this point.